# ampersand in the option value in html selection

Tags: html, special-characters, ampersand

Do you know why I put ampersand in the option value is not rendered correctly

```
option(value="John &amp; Ken") John &amp; Ken
```

I have put this on the option value but then it is not showed. It is correct or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you are trying to do exactly?

If you are using JavaScript to add an option element to a select element then you do not need to use the HTML entity `$amp;` to add to the text.

```
var select = document.getElementById('myselect'),
option = document.createElement('option');
option.innerHTML = "John & Ken";
option.value = "John & Ken";
select.add(option);
```